# Is there a way to enable semantic search programatically using Pythion API in Azure AI Search

Tags: azure-search-.net-sdk

I have configured `Azure AI Search` Service. When I try to use it using `python` api, I get error `Semantic search is not enabled for this service.`. I have to manually go to portal and enable `semantic ranking` by selecting the `standard` plan. Can't I enable the plan using API?

Answer (score 0):

While there's no direct Python API call to enable semantic search within a service, here's how you can achieve it programmatically:

**Leverage Azure Management Libraries:**

Install the Azure Management Libraries for Python: pip install azure-mgmt-search
Authenticate using a suitable method (service principal, managed identity, etc.).
Use the SearchManagementClient to execute the create_or_update operation on the service, setting the sku to standard.
Code Example:

Python

```
from azure.mgmt.search import SearchManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

# Authenticate (replace with your credentials)
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id="<client-id>", secret="<client-secret>", tenant="<tenant-id>"
)

# Create SearchManagementClient
client = SearchManagementClient(credentials, "<subscription-id>")

# Enable semantic search
client.services.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name="<resource-group-name>",
    service_name="<service-name>",
    sku= { "name": "standard" }
)
```

or even you can try to Utilize Azure REST API.